# Prove or disprove that L = {$a^nb^m$ | $m ≠ 3n + 5$} is a regular

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

How can I prove or disprove that $L = \lbrace a^nb^m$ | $m ≠ 3n + 5 \rbrace$ is a regular language?

**Attempt** 
Assume $L$ is regular, then its complement $L^\complement$ is also regular. 
$L^\complement = \lbrace a^nb^{3n+5} \mid n ∈ N \rbrace$. 
By the pumping lemma, there exists a constant natural $p$.
Let $s = a^pb^{3p+5}$ ∈ $L^\complement$. $|s| \geq p$ so there exists a split $s =xyz$ where $|x| \geq 1$, $|xy| \leq p$. 
If I choose $i = 2$, then $xy^2z = a^{|x|}a^{2|y|}a^{p-|x|-|y|}b^{3p+5}=a^{p+|v|}b^{3p+5} \notin L^\complement$. 
But I'm not sure how to continue to disprove that L isn't regular.

Comment: are you sure that $\{a^nb^m$ | $m ≠ 3n + 5\}$ is really the complement of $\mathcal L$ ?

Comment: @Zag I'm saying that the complement of L is {$a^nb^m$
  | m=3n+5}...

Comment: I meant $=$ not $\neq$ sorry. But still, a word like $ba$ is in the complement of $\mathcal L$.

Comment: However your argument still holds, the word $a^{p+|v|}b^{2p+5} \in \mathcal L$, so $\mathcal L^{\complement}$ is not regular by the pumping lemma. Hence, $\mathcal L$ is not regular. Sorry, the fact that $\mathcal L^{\complement}$ is not well defined does not harm the proof (you studied $\mathcal L^{\complement} \cap a^*b^*$ instead of $\mathcal L^{\complement}$).

Comment: @Zag is my answer to the question correct now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $L$ is regular, then its complement $L^\complement$ is also regular. 
Since $L^\complement$ is regular then $L^\complement$⋂ {$a^*b^*$} = $L_2$ is also regular.
$L_2 = \lbrace a^nb^{3n+5} \mid n ∈ N \rbrace$. 
By the pumping lemma, there exists a constant natural $p$.
Let $s = a^pb^{3p+5}$ ∈ $L_2$. $|s| \geq p$ so there exists a split $s =xyz$ where $|x| \geq 1$, $|xy| \leq p$. 
If I choose $i = 2$, then $xy^2z = a^{|x|}a^{2|y|}a^{p-|x|-|y|}b^{3p+5}=a^{p+|v|}b^{3p+5} \notin L_2$. 
This contradicts the pumping lemma, therefore $L_2$ isn't a regular language as well as $L$.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?

Comment: This is a complete answer. I removed the last line.

Comment: seems correct to me